# Insert some char between <li>s

Tags: css

I have a framework which generates some html and echos them. In a particular situation, the framework generates a HTML numeration:

```
<ul>
     <li class="foo">A</li>
     <li class="foo">B</li>
     <li class="foo">C</li>
</ul>
```

which is displayed in an in-line manner like `A B C`. How can I change the `foo` class in CSS code get text to be displays like `A * B * C` ?

Comment: You can use before or after pseudo....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modulo browser support, you should be able to do it with `:first-child`:

```
.foo::before {
    content: "* "
}
.foo:first-child::before {
    content: ""
}
```

Example:

```css
.foo {
  display: inline-block;
}
.foo::before {
  content: "* "
}
.foo:first-child::before {
  content: ""
}
```

```html
<ul>
     <li class="foo">A</li>
     <li class="foo">B</li>
     <li class="foo">C</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
li.foo::after {content: '*'}
li.foo:last-child::after {content: ''}
```

```html
<ul>
     <li class="foo">A</li>
     <li class="foo">B</li>
     <li class="foo">C</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That adds a `*` after the last one.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Right, but i was called away from the computer before i could fix it. Fixed now. :)

Comment: Okay, *now* it doesn't.